# How do I enable "!!" in fish?

Tags: shell, configuration, sudo, fish

I often used `$ sudo !!` while using bash. After switching to fish, I noticed this no longer works. Due to search engines not supporting search for special characters, this has been particularly difficult to figure out on my own. I presume I just need to add/change one line in the config, but I don't know what that would be.

Comment: Try googling for "fish history expansion".

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q seems  more appropriate for https://superuser.com  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fish shell [deliberately omits history substitution](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html#faq-history).

Comment: This is good to know. However I do still need a workaround as my keyboard does not have a home key, which basically entirely negates all convenience their alternative method intended to add.

Comment: You can press Ctrl-A to move the cursor to the beginning of the line, if that's what you are really asking about.

Answer (score 5):

Oldish question, but I'm surprised that there's been no mention of fish shell's "pre-pend sudo" keybinding <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>.

With the default, out-of-the-box keybindings, `sudo !!` can be accomplished with either:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>
- or <kbd>↑</kbd> followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>, but that does move your finger a bit far from the "home row" for those that care (and I do).

The first key-chord repeats the previous command, then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> prepends `sudo` to it.

Edit:  With fish 3.2 and later, one of my favorite new features is that you don't even need to retrieve the previous line via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>.  Just <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> with no other text typed at the prompt will result in the prompt being automatically populated with `sudo` + the last command typed.

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways of implementing this using shell hacks listed at https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/wiki/Bash-Style-Command-Substitution-and-Chaining-(!!-!%24-&&-%7C%7C)

For example:

```
function bind_bang
  switch (commandline -t)
  case "!"
    commandline -t $history[1]; commandline -f repaint
  case "*"
    commandline -i !
  end
end

function bind_dollar
  switch (commandline -t)
  case "!"
    commandline -t ""
    commandline -f history-token-search-backward
  case "*"
    commandline -i '$'
  end
end

function fish_user_key_bindings
  bind ! bind_bang
  bind '$' bind_dollar
end

funcsave bind_bang bind_dollar fish_user_key_bindings
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to install the [Fisher](https://github.com/jorgebucaran/fisher) package manager; and then install the package [!!](https://github.com/oh-my-fish/plugin-bang-bang), e.g.:

```
$ fisher install oh-my-fish/plugin-bang-bang
```

p.s.

Not only do you get back the use of !! (last command used) but also !$ (last command arguments.)

You could also use the plugin through the older installer [omf](https://github.com/oh-my-fish/oh-my-fish).

Why reinvent the wheel when you have an easy to use a package manager like Fisher.